# How are Sephardi Sifrei Torah assembled?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, sefer-torah

I rarely daven in Sephardi shuls, so I'm curious as to how Sephardi Sifrei Torah are "assembled" from the time it is written on parchment until it is put into the case.

Ashkenazi Sifrei Torah are "simple" by comparison. You put the parchment on *atzei chayim* and it doesn't matter much how tall, thick or heavy they really are, as long as the length is taller than the length of the parchment.

But I'm curious how the Sephardi ones are planned and assembled. There are no *atzei chayim* I gather as they are placed inside the case. Do they "custom size" the case to for the size of the parchment? What is the parchment attached to and then how does it stay standing upright in the case?

Please explain the "assembly" process.

Comment: Isnt it just like an Ashkenazi Torah with a box around it? They probably custom size the case as much as Ashkenazim custom size the poles. Undoubtedly most are standard sizes. I'm not sure what you think is so different that you're confused

Answer (score 3):

Here is an [advertisement video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=b7hDDrYQGZU) from YouTube, where they show in detail the *tik.* As you can see there, the poles are attached to the box and can rotate. The scroll is just attached to these poles in the same way as in the Ashkenazi practice. I assume there are standard parchment sizes, but since many of these cases are ornamented and expensive, you can order it in any size.